# Asp.net Ajax not working with wordpress permalinks on

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wordpress

I have installed wordpress on my windows server.

A sub folder of the wordpress website has an asp.net application.

I noticed after changing the permalinks to wordpress default http://mywebsitename.co.uk/?p=123

to any other option it asked me to add the following the web.config file

```
    <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
       <match url="*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
```

However, this has now caused my ajax to fail in my asp.net folder. It gives me error Sys not defined.

Is there a solution to fix them have permalinks and my ajax both working.

I feel it is to do with the following line of code

```
   <match url="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax was not working because the WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd could not be found.

I solved this by

1. First removing the rule from the Web.config file, the ajax was now working  without any issues. I went into the source code and reached the WebResource.axd files and downloaded them. If the ajax still does not work, please clear your web cache.
2. I then added the rule back into the web.config file.
3. I copied the files WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd into the websites root folder.
4. Clear your browser cache and test the ajax. This should work now.

Now your asp.net ajax as well as the wordpress permalinks should be able to co-exist.